# how to convert part of a thymleaf code to jsp code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jsp

```html
 <div>
     <h3>List of Documents</h3>
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Download Link</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr th:each="doc:${docs}">
           <td th:text="${doc.Id}" />
           <td th:text="${doc.docName}"/>
           <td><a th:href="@{'/downloadFile/'+${doc.id}}">Download</a></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

i am trying to convert this thymleaf code line to jsp code

can somebody do some suggestions .  thanks in advance

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception occurs and it does not download the file...using the thymleaf the code is working okay. but i am working on a jsp spring boot applications and i wanted to change that line to jsp code

Comment: thank u everyone i had fixed it.<c:forEach items="${mastertransactionlists}" var="transaction">
      <tr>
       <td>${transaction.createdDate}</td>
       <td>${transaction.createdBy}</td>
       <td>${transaction.transactiondocumentid}</td>
       <td>${transaction.docName}</td>
             <td><a href="downloadFile/${transaction.id}">Download</a></td>
                       
       <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success"
        href="">Update</a>
       <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
        href="">Details</a></td>
        
      </tr>
     </c:forEach>